# Proof of 3-fold Tensor Uniqueness

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra, tensor-decomposition

In the notes linked below Professor Roughgarden states Theorem 3.1 without proof.

http://timroughgarden.org/s17/l/l10.pdf

Any ideas how one would go about proving this statement or references to where I would find such a proof?

Thanks

Comment: the algorithm from this theorem (explained in section 3.2) seems to justify the uniqueness of the decomposition -- if we know the specified decomposition exists, then the algorithm recovers it with probability $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical result. (in fact Theorem 1 holds under less restrictive assumptions).
This is the proof for $k=n$. Let $U$, $V$, and $W$ be $n\times n$ matrices formed by the vectors $u$, $v$, and $w$, respectively.
It can be verified that the decomposition in Theorem 1 can be written as a set of $n$ matrix equations.
$$
A(:,:,1) = U diag(W(1,:))V^T,\dots, A(:,:,n) = U diag(W(n,:))V^T,$$ where $A(:,:,m)$ denotes the $m$th frontal slice of the tensor $A$ and $W(m,:)$
denotes the $m$th row of $W$. If $A(:,:,2)$ is nonsingular (=invertible), then $$A(:,:,1)A(:,:,2)^{-1} = U diag(W(1,:))V^T(U diag(W(1,:))V^T)^{-1} = U diag(W(1,:))diag(W(2,:))^{-1} U^{-1}.$$ The matrix $diag(W(1,:))diag(W(2,:))^{-1}$
is diagonal, so
$$
A(:,:,1)A(:,:,2)^{-1}=U diag(W(1,:))diag(W(2,:))^{-1} U^{-1}$$ is the eigenvalue decomposition of $A(:,:,1)A(:,:,2)^{-1}$. It is known that if  the
 the eigenvalues of $A(:,:,1)A(:,:,2)^{-1}$ are distinct (that is, the  diagonal entries  of 
$diag(W(1,:))diag(W(2,:))$), then the eigenvectors of $A(:,:,1)A(:,:,2)^{-1}$ can be uniquelly recovered (up to permutation and scaling of course). This gives you the way to compute matrix $U$ (This also proves that $U$ is unique up to permutation and scaling of its columns).

In general, $A(:,:,2)$ can be singular or  $A(:,:,1)A(:,:,2)^{-1}$ may have repeated eigenvalues, so one replaces matrix equations with $A(:,:,1)$ and $A(:,:,2)$ by  generic linear combinations of all matrix equations. It can be shown that both new matrix slices $A(:,:,1)$ and $A(:,:,2)$ are nonsingular. Note that
generic linear combinations will also affect the diagonal matrices $diag(W(1,:))$ and  $diag(W(2,:)$. Again it can be shown that   for generic linear combinations
the new diagonal matrix $diag(W(1,:))diag(W(2,:))$ will have distinct entries on the main diagonal. (That is why, in the Algorithm, the first step is to take random $x$ and $y$). The uniqueness of $V$ and $W$  can be proved in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please list other references for the result (since you mentioned it is classical) if you have them. Particularly, if there are any references that prove the result in a different way, maybe a coordinate free way

Comment: There are many references on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition.
The earliest one is [3] (see p. 61). Other references are [24,26,27] and probably [25]. 
Proposition 12.4.3.2 in  [J.M. Landsberg, Tensors: Geometry and Applications, 2012] is the  coordinate free proof (for generic tensors over $\mathbb C$).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please take a look at the unanswered question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593571/proof-of-unique-coordinatization-of-tensor-space-once-bases-are-chosen