# Uniqueness of the matrix representation of tensors

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

Note that both maps below satisfy the universal property of the tensor product. 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} &\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \\
   \begin{bmatrix} 
    a_1 \\
    a_2 \\ 
   \end{bmatrix} \times 
   \begin{bmatrix} 
    b_ 1 \\
    b_2 \\ 
   \end{bmatrix}
&\mapsto
   \begin{bmatrix} 
    a_1 b_ 1 & a_1 b_2 \\
    a_2 b_1 & a_2 b_2 \\ 
   \end{bmatrix} 
&\begin{bmatrix} 
    a_1 \\
    a_2 \\ 
   \end{bmatrix} \times 
   \begin{bmatrix} 
    b_ 1 \\
    b_2 \\ 
   \end{bmatrix}
&\mapsto
   \begin{bmatrix} 
    a_1 b_ 2 & a_1 b_1 \\
    a_2 b_2 & a_2 b_1 \\ 
   \end{bmatrix} \\ 
(a_i) \times (b_i) &\mapsto (c_{ij} = a_i b_j) &(a_i) \times (b_i) &\mapsto (c_{ij} = a_i b_{\tau(j)}) \text{ where $\tau = (12) \in S_2$} 
\end{align*}
Similarly, for $(\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_d) \in S_{n_1} \times S_{n_2} \times \dots S_{n_d}$, the map
\begin{gather*}
K^{n_1} \times K^{n_2} \times \dots \times K^{n_d} \  \xrightarrow{\Gamma_{(\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_d)}} \ K^{n_1 \times n_2 \times \dots \times n_d} \\
(x_i^1) \times (x_i^2) \times \dots \times (x_i^d) \ \mapsto \ (c_{{i_1}{i_2}\dots{i_d}} = x^1_{\sigma_1(i_1)} x^2_{\sigma_2(i_2)} \dots x^d_{\sigma_d(i_d)})
\end{gather*} satisfies the universal property.

Are these the only maps that satisfy the universal property? Formally, is it true that:

if $K^{n_1} \times K^{n_2} \times \dots \times K^{n_d} \  \xrightarrow{\Gamma} \ K^{n_1 \times n_2 \times \dots \times n_d}$ satisfies the universal property of the tensor product, then $\Gamma = \Gamma_{(\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_d)}$ for some $(\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_d) \in S_{n_1} \times S_{n_2} \times \dots S_{n_d}$.

I asked a similar question here
[Proof of unique coordinatization of tensor space once bases are chosen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593571/proof-of-unique-coordinatization-of-tensor-space-once-bases-are-chosen)
but I think I confused people in how the question was stated, so I am writing it in a different way here. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are many more such "tensor maps". For instance, (I think, as you didn't specify exactly which tensor product property you wanted) you can compose with any automorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ to create a different tensor map.

For instance, for any invertible matrix $P$, $(a,b) \longmapsto P^{-1}\Gamma_{\operatorname{id},\operatorname{id}}(a,b)P$ should satisfy the property.

For a concrete example, take $P=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and consider the map $$\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ a_2\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\end{bmatrix} \longmapsto \begin{bmatrix} a_2b_2 & -a_2b_1 \\-a_1b_2 & a_1b_1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank, your map is indeed another tensor map. But not every automorphism of $R^{2 \times 2}$ will work. Do you know of a characterization of such tensor maps?